# SAP dashboard installation

Tags: business-objects, dashboard-designer

Our company decided to use dashboards for Business Objects.

We already installed SBOP BI PLATFORM 4.1 SP04 CLIENT TOOLS WINDOWS (32B) however dashboard is not part of this. I tried to google and find the installer on SAP website, but wasn't successful.

Will you be kind enough to guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate installer.  From the download site, navigate to:

- Installations and Upgrades

  - Browse Our Download Catalog

    - Analytics Solutions

      - SBOP DASHBOARDS (XCELSIUS)

        - SBOP DASHBOARDS 4.1

          - Installation and Upgrade

            - WINDOWS

Comment: Thanks for your response Joe

Comment: @nimamahboob - Rather than posting a thank-you comment, you should accept the answer if it solved your problem (and upvote it too). A thank-you comment doesn't help at all (and nobody knows if Joe's answer is, indeed, correct.

Comment: @ David Makogon. I am going to try what Joe said, I believe he is right. The SAP website is not really user friendly. As a result I couldnt find the dashboard under our account and as you may know based on your account privileges they customize the downloads. So now I am checking our company account and our privileges. As soon as I find out I will update the post!!